# "Ignore errors" in Excel XML

Tags: xml, excel, ms-office

thanks for your help!

I'm basically creating an excel file via XML... everything is fine except that when I open the file in excel, it has that annoying green arrow on each cell... the one that you click and has the option "ignore error"... I basically want the XML to have a line that would tell excell to ignore these "errors".

I DO NOT want to go to excel propierties and modify how excel shows this... the reason is that the excel file will be open by hundreds of people in different computers... I just want something in the XML to notify excel to ignore these errors... here is my XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
      <Borders/>
      <Font/>
      <Interior/>
      <NumberFormat/>
      <Protection/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s_body">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s_aqua">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
      </Borders>
      <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
      <Interior ss:Color="#CCFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s_yellow">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
      </Borders>
      <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
      <Interior ss:Color="#FFFF40" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s_green">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
      </Borders>
      <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
      <Interior ss:Color="#6FFF6F" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s_wrap">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s8">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
      </Borders>
      <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="24" ss:Bold="1"/>
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="11" ss:ExpandedRowCount="9" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1">
      <Column ss:Index="1"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="70"/>
      <Column ss:Index="2"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="120"/>
      <Column ss:Index="3"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="50"/>
      <Column ss:Index="4"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="50"/>
      <Column ss:Index="5"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
      <Column ss:Index="6"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="85"/>
      <Column ss:Index="7"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95"/>
      <Column ss:Index="8"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="55"/>
      <Column ss:Index="9"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="103"/>
      <Column ss:Index="10"  ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="90"/>
      <Column ss:Index="11" ss:StyleID="s_wrap" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
      <Row ss:Height="30">
        <Cell ss:MergeAcross="10" ss:StyleID="s8">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Example</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_aqua">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_aqua">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_aqua">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 3</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_yellow">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_yellow">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 5</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_yellow">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 6</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_yellow">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 7</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_green">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 8</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_green">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 9</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_green">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 10</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_green">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Column 11</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">800000000051</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">434412321</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_body">
          <Data ss:Type="String">3665382-4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
        </Data>
      </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_body">
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
        </Data>
      </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_body">
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">800000000051</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">434412321</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_body">
          <Data ss:Type="String">3665382-4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
        </Data>
      </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_body">
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
        </Data>
      </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s_body">
          <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
    <DataValidation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <Range>R2C2:R1000C2</Range>
      <Type>List</Type>
      <CellRangeList/>
      <Value>"Red, Black, Green"</Value>
    </DataValidation>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 0):

The green markers indicate that there are *strings* in a cell that resemble Excel of being a *number*.

Try `ss:Type="Number"` for all numeric values instead of `ss:Type="String"` and you get rid of the green markers, e.g.

```
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">800000000051</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">434412321</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">Some Text</Data>
    </Cell>
```